# How to sort in group for infragistics ultragrid?

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a problem about Ultragrid group and sort.

My data.

```
"1"
"19"
"2"
"3"
```

I want sort data:

> "1" , "2" , "3" , "19"

How to sort and group that ?

```
e.Layout.Bands[0].SortedColumns.Add("GuestName", false, true);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

UltraGridColumn has [SortComparer](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2016.1/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v16.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~SortComparer.html) property. This property allows you to assign your own comparer. So, go ahead, implement your own sort comparer and assign it to the column you need.